# JSLint: How do disable the check for unsafe characters for comments?

Tags: config, jslint

Is it possible to disable the check for unsafe characters in comments?
My team is in germany and so we all use german umlaut-marks.

Comment: Just for fun, can you paste in some of your code with "unsafe" characters so I *know* I'm watching what you see happening in JSLint?

Comment: We have some comments like `// Wir können dies und das tun` @ruffin

Comment: So kinda what I thought. Try [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eqv7YK5N) at [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) -- no errors. How are you executing JSLint? As a plugin in an editor?